# Evaluation of Half Dirac Delta Function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, closed-form

$\delta^{(1/2)}_\mu(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|k|^{1/2}e^{ikx}e^{-\mu|k|}dk$ which provides the half-Dirac delta distribution in the limiting case of $\mu\to0$.

I know the solution of $\delta^{(1/2)}_\mu=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|k|^{1/2}e^{ikx}e^{-\mu|k|}dk$ is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi}}(x^2+\mu^2)^{-3/4}\cos(\frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{\mu}))$, but I would appreciate knowing how the evaluation is accomplished.

I can get to the point of $\delta^{(1/2)}_\mu=2\int_0^{\infty}\cos(kx)e^{-\mu k}k^{1/2}dk$, but beyond here I have no idea.

EDIT: Obvious thing that I missed on the first go-about is that this is related to the Laplace transform of $k^{1/2}\cos(k)$. Evaluating this seems "straight-forward" albeit incredibly nontrivial.

Comment: would you mind to explain what a ''half dirac delta distribution'' exactly is?

Comment: @tired given his definition, it is (up to a constant) the fractional $1/2$ derivative of $\delta$ such that $\delta^{(1/2)} \ast f = \frac{d^{1/2} f}{dx^{1/2}}$ (in the same way that $\delta' \ast f = f'$)

Comment: @tired I wasn't sure the best way to name it in English, though looking at the notation again, it being the $1/2$ derivative of the Dirac delta makes some logical sense. The distribution appeared in a paper mentioned in a homework assignment, [H. Aratyn, Fermions from Bosons in 2+1 dimensions, Phys. Rev. D 28 (1983) 2016-18](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.28.2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said you need some complex analysis for showing that

$$\int_0^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-zt}dt = \Gamma(a) z^{-a}, \qquad \text{Re}(z) > 0,\ \text{Re}(a) > 0$$
The proof is that for $\text{Re}(z) > 0$   the LHS and the RHS are analytic in $z$, and for $z \in (0,\infty)$ they are equal (change of variable $u = zt$), hence by [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) (or by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), or by the [Cauchy integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem)) they are equal for every $\text{Re}(z) > 0$.

Then you have (for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mu > 0$)
$$2\pi \delta^{(1/2)}_\mu(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |k|^{1/2} e^{-\mu |k|} e^{i k x}dk = \int_0^\infty k^{1/2} (e^{-(\mu+ix) k}+e^{-(\mu-ix) k})dk$$ $$ = \Gamma(3/2) ((\mu+ix)^{-3/2}+(\mu-ix)^{-3/2}) =  \Gamma(3/2)\, 2\,\text{Re}((\mu+ix)^{-3/2})$$ $$ = 2 \Gamma(3/2) \, |\mu+ix|^{-3/2} \cos(\text{arg}((\mu+ix)^{-3/2})) =  \sqrt{\pi}\, (\mu^2+x^2)^{-3/4} \cos(\frac{3}{2}\arctan(x/\mu))$$

---

There is a plot of $\delta_\mu^{(1/2)}$ for $\mu = 1,0.7,0.5$ : 
[image]

Comment: I greatly appreciate the work, and the really solid explanation. Have a bit of reading to do on the identity theorem now. I'm a physicist by training, and my undergraduate degree didn't include the most rigor in its mathematical treatment of things, thus why I'm now taking a solid mathematical methods course during my PhD program. This appeared as a sort of extra "Could you do this if I hadn't given you the formula?" sort of question on a recent homework assignment and to be honest, the answer for most of the students in the class was a resounding "No," myself included.